# Why can't I share my ShinyApp with shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a ShinyApp in R, which works fine locally. But when I try to put it on shinyapps.io, it points to the line where I read in a CSV file and says 
"Paths should be to files within the project directory".

The CSV file and the app.R file are in my working directory.

Comment: hi @madhatter5, if my answer solves your issue, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload a shiny app to shinyapps.io, all companion files need to be inside a folder named "data" in the same directory where the `app.R` file is.

Solution:

1. Create a "data" folder where your app.R file is
2. Copy your CSV file there
3. Update your code accordingly i.e. `mydata <- read.csv('data/mydata.csv')`
4. Try uploading to shinyapps.io again